# How to bulk (import /export) to (data extensions / lists) with (soap / api / sdk)?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am writing a hub exchange application.

And I am trying to do bulk import / export data into data extensions / subscriber lists ( since they could potentially be huge. )
 I will have a JWT from clients using our application in Exact Target.

Looking at the fuel api/ fuel sdk ... I could not see how to import more than one dataextension row at a time.  My current ideas are:

1) Figure out how to use the fuel api: 
   https://code.exacttarget.com/api/dataeventsasync-rowset . 
  Seems like it might do bulk import .. but the example they show did not work, and no error reported.

2)  Use soap api to ( import/export ) the rows. Would this work with just an oauth access token and the savon gem ( I am using ruby )?  If so, any chance I could get a hint as to how to do this?
    What is the max number of records I could send/get at once?

3)  FTP the data somehow?  Would this work with just an oauth access token?

I would appreciate any help or guidance at all.  I am kind of stumped at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to Salesforce Stack Exchange. We're currently investigating

Comment: I don't think there is a simple answer to your question really - lots of ways to approach this and most of it will depend on how your application is set up.  Realistically, trying to outline all the possibilities would take a very, very long answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've been able to make the REST API work with a single entry and multiple entries. Below are the details.

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataeventsasync/key:KoffeeSubscribers/rowset?access_token=…

Content-Type: application/json

    [
        {
            "keys":{
                    "CustomerNumber":"15"
                    },            
            "values":{
                    "EmailAddress":"brinkleyr2@gmail.com"
                    }
        } ]
```

if you're looking for multiple entries the json syntax looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "keys":{
                "CustomerNumber":"16"
                },            
        "values":{
                "EmailAddress":"brinkleyr2@gmail.com"
                }
    },
    {
        "keys":{
                "CustomerNumber":"17"
                },            
        "values":{
                "EmailAddress":"brinkleyr2@gmail.com"
                }
    }
]
```

A couple of caveats:

1. Any syntax error in the body text is going to produce an error 400. In short Pilot error is pretty easy to achieve.
2. Success results might not show up in the MC until you logout and log back in. At least they didn't for me.

**Let me know if you still have a problem.**

Comment: This was helpful and I finally got the rest api working to send the data into the data extension, but the send limit here was about 10K records, because the exact target server gave me a 504 Gateway Timeout error, when the data was too big .. so this would be a less great solution for 1 million records .. I reckon.

Comment: I also tried doing requests in parallel, with em-http-request ruby gem. But the exact target servers did not seem to allow it, and only the first request succeeded, while the rest failed.

Comment: the REST API docs specify that this is possible: https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/postDataExtensionRowsetByKeyAsync.html although unfortunately the fuel sdk does not have this functionality afaik.