# Adding Bulk data to Data Extension Object in Exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, api-27

I have a number of CSV's with each CSV having a million row sets. Now i have to send those CSV's to particular Data Extension Object in Exact target. I am aware of [adding a row to data extension object](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_data_to_data_extension_object/) , But is there any option where we can add millions of row sets at one go Using Axis 2(Java)? The answer that i would expect is similar to the import we see in the UI of Exact Target account, where we see a FTP URL if the data is more than 20 mb (The approach should be a code based approach and only java based). Please provide your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Also i would recommed your suggestion to have a SOAP communication. FUEL Api usage is ruled out in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I would recommend is a combination solution, java on your end, and setting up the ET app to do what you need it to do.

1. First, verify you have access to the ET FTP server.  If you don't have credentials, reach out to your ET representative who can get them for you.
2. Next, read up on [File Transfer Activities](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/) and [Import Activities](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/). You will need to use each of them to set up the how files will be moved into Data Extensions.
3. Now on to automation studio: [Triggered Automations](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/).  You will set up a triggered automation to listen to a folder, that uses the File Transfer Activity and Import Activity that you've already set up.
4. On your end, use java to push a file to that directory on the ET FTP server.  The automation will pick it up, and you're done!

Comment: Thanks @Timothy.To get more clarification on this, is there a BUlk API for ET like one that SalesForce has?

Comment: And can i also do this triggered automation using the java code, (calling the existing Import definition template?) which i see in this URL http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/starting_an_import_definition_via_the_web_service_api/

Answer (score 2):

A better solution, imo, is to use the REST API to accomplish this:

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:SomeKey/rowset


[
    {
        "keys":{
                "Email": "someone@example.com"
                },
        "values":{
                "LastLogin": "2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
                "IsActive": true,
                "FirstName": "John",
                "FollowerCount": 2,
                "LastName": "Smith"
                }
    },
    {
        "keys": {
                "Email": "someone2@example.com"
                },
        "values":{
                "LastLogin": "2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
                "IsActive": true,
                "FirstName": "Jane",
                "FollowerCount": 2,
                "LastName": "Smith"
                }
    }
]
```

also see the following answer which describes this: [How to bulk (import /export) to (data extensions / lists) with (soap / api / sdk)?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27612/how-to-bulk-import-export-to-data-extensions-lists-with-soap-api-sdk?rq=1)