# Loading Massive data into Data Extension using API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, dataextensions

I want to load about a million records into a Data Extension from an external system. Wondering what would be the most efficient way to achieve that?

If I use SOAP/ REST API, how many records should I pass to the API call every time?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet, due to the large audience is to export the records into a csv and then compress it and send it to the FTP associated with your SFMC account. You can then set up a program in automation studio that is triggered based on this file drop that decompresses it and imports it into your account. From everything I have read, this is the best/easiest way to handle massive bulk imports.

If you are determined to use API, you will likely want to do a bunch of [asynchronous upserts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKeyAsync.htm) using the REST API. I believe the limit is at around 10k per call though.

Similar questions/answers:

[ExactTarget: Common data loading strategies?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50580/exacttarget-common-data-loading-strategies)

[Adding Bulk data to Data Extension Object in Exact target](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40175/adding-bulk-data-to-data-extension-object-in-exact-target)

[How to bulk (import /export) to (data extensions / lists) with (soap / api / sdk)?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27612/how-to-bulk-import-export-to-data-extensions-lists-with-soap-api-sdk?rq=1)

Comment: +1 for a File Import from FTP.  Depends on the cleanliness of your data, but you could save yourself some trouble by using a tab-delimited file instead CSV.

Comment: +1 for SFTP,  If you don't want to setup automations via WebUI, or have a dynamic columns definition, I suggest to create ImportDefinition programmatically by mapping the fields ,  then perform the import definition. I've done it for List Import, DE should be very similar.